# No transform from [base_link] to [/map]

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know similar questions have been asked but I think mine is a little different.

I have a custom robot which is running Hector_Slam and the navigation stack etc, all is working well.  However I been advised to add a model (URDF) to the project so I can tell the system where my new sensors are going to go.

My Fixed frame is /map or I can use /laser

I created my robot which its top level thing seems to be base_link.  It complains that there is No transform from [base_link] to [/map]?

It also complains there is no No transform from [lwheel] to [/map] and so on?  If I fix the base_link error will it make the others go away? (the wheels are linked to base_link)

In my Hector Launch File I see lots or references to

```
<param name="base_frame" value="base_frame"/>
```

But nothing to base_link

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253505/no-transform-from-%5Bbase_link%5D-to-%5B/map%5D/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-01**:
To make things slightly simpler:

> If I fix the base_link error will it make the others go away? (the wheels are linked to base_link)

yes.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-01**:
Man I need to buy you a beer or a pack.  Any idea how I link base_link to map?

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-01**:
Randomly I changed the base_link to base_frame however the wheel etc error did not go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in the `base_frame`  parameter, you should put the name of your "main" tf frame, it usually is `base_link` or `base_footprint`.
do you have odom? if not, set the `odom_frame` to the same as the `base_frame`
basically follow the guidelines [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot#Setup).

also there is no wheel in your tf tree, so probably something is wrong in your URDF.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-02**:
I do have a base_footprint, is that the same as base_Link.  in My URDF, when I change base_link to base_frame, the main error goes away however, what do I need to do to link my wheels up?  I do have /odom_frame vai Hector